# get current page view in drupal

Tags: drupal, view

How to get the view of the current page in drupal.

I have a  filter, whenever the user enters the search item, the view is changed.

`$view = views_get_current_view();`

does not work.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me :

```
$view = views_get_page_view();
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation, the data should be in

`$page_data = page_manager_get_current_page();`

when called from `MYTHEME_preprocess_page()`.

You may need to `print_r` the data, but I think the view name will be set as `$page_data['handler']->subtask`.  I have used this in themes before, but depending on how your site is put together, this may not always work.